# Is it okay to cross-post my own posts on multiple separate WordPress.org sites? Is it good or bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, blog, negative-seo

I write blog posts for multiple WordPress.org blogs and where content overlaps, I wonder if I should post it separately on multiple blogs or not. Often this happens with posts I write to my personal blog which are pertinent for groups I volunteer for who share my interests. Will this kind of cross-posting hurt or help search engine optimization for the sites, and is there anything other than SEO to consider related to this? If anything, I imagine linking a post between multiple websites improves SEO for either/both since both become linked to by at least one additional node of the internet.

If it is OK to cross-post to different, separately hosted Wordpress.org blogs on independent URLs, are there better and worse ways to do it? Is copy and pasting the content between sites any better or worse than using a plugin to do it aside from work involved either way?

Comment: This is completely covered by our catch all question on duplicate content: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to manage it so, that publishing blogs give you a cross-site canonical to your page, to original article, than it is the best case.

If you have no influence on canonicalization, than simply don't worry. The whole web lives by republishing and cross-posting, and Google is pretty good in getting to know, where is the original.

To make Google's job easier make use of structured data article markup (at least on your own blog) and make an array of your social profiles for the author property. This way gives Google unambiguous info about you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you give more detail on "cross-site canonical"? I have administrative access to both blogs, domains, and each of their host servers. But I don't think I understand what cross-site canonical refers to fully.

Comment: @cr0 Use a canonical tag on all copies of the post, where the canonical tag points to the single "most official" URL that you want to show up in search results.